# Main branch rollback and merge child branch missing changes

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Lets say i have 2 branches A (main), B(child)

I merge B to A and as a result create changeset 200 in A

Then I move B branch to Retired folder resulting changeset 201

After that I create a new branch C from A resulting changeset 202

Roll back changeset 200 in main branch A resulting changeset 203

Now if i merge Branch C to A as a Reverse Intergration I want to get all the back all the rollback changes in Branch A

But i get the message Nothing to Merge

note i used only Visual studio not command prompt. Any solution woukd be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you try to merge from Branch C to A, there is actually **no** candidate in Branch C (changesets in the source Branch C that have not yet been merged into the destination Branch A), so you get message Nothing to Merge.

You can try to do some modification in Branch C to get a new changeset in Branch C, then perform a merge to Branch A, or you can use [Merge command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-command) with **/force** option to force this merge. **/force** option will ignore the merge history and merge the specified changes from the source into the destination.

Comment: But will that get all the changes i rolled back in changeset 200

Comment: Might be a silly question, but did you check in each of the merges and rollbacks?

Comment: @cece ding no it doesn't bring back 200 changeset changed

Comment: @AllSpark Since your C is branched from A changeset 200, C should have contained the changes in changeset 200.

Comment: So even its rolled backed in parent it wouldn't matter?? the changes are in C though its very strange tea do this

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the changes in 200? Then why do you branch C from 200?

Comment: branch C from A resulting changeset 202 with change and on changeset 203 i rolled back changes in main branch so Branch C still has the changes

Comment: Changeset 202 is the change that branch C from A, it's on branch C. Changeset 203 is on branch A. There is actually no candidateon Branch C (changesets after 202), so you get message Nothing to Merge.